# Changing values with MySQL in a table over time

Tags: mysql

I have a resource table for a game I'm trying to code, and each resource has a fixed income rate over time. But I can't find any description on how to increase the stored values of the MySQL Table over time automatically.

I'm using NetBeans to connect the program with the database, but I want the values to be updated on the server without the need to run the program. Otherwise I would just have had the time recorded and just add the time difference value.

Is there a way of doing this?

**Table:**

Player ID:    1

Gold:       100

Wood:       100

Increase rate: 50 per hour

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using [Cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and schedule some script to run.
Otherwise you can simply calculate the time elapsed from the beginning and (whithout updating your DB) calculate values based on the time when your program is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a cron job on the server, that runs a query to update the values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by adding a scheduled event like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-privileges.html). However, if you update the value in the database, the value/variable stored by the program will not be updated in real-time: you have to query the database for the updated value.